# Additional space in div using Yii widgets

Tags: css, yii

There is the following PHP code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="captcha">
<? $this->widget('CCaptcha', array('showRefreshButton'=>false)); ?>
</div><?php echo $form->textField($model, 'verifyCode', array('class'=>'resume-form-input')); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Done', array('class'=>'button-style')); ?>
</div>
```

As you can see, this "row" contains captcha widget, text field, submit button. But this code looks bad. If I format it in the following way:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="captcha">
<? $this->widget('CCaptcha', array('showRefreshButton'=>false)); ?>
</div>
<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'verifyCode', array('class'=>'resume-form-input')); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Done', array('class'=>'button-style')); ?>
</div>
```

I've got one additional space before text field. What's a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the rendered output, I'd guess because `input` per default behave similar to `display: inline` or `inline-block` elements. That means that whitespaces like line breaks are rendered. Wrap it inside another `<div/>`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="captcha">
        <? $this->widget('CCaptcha', array('showRefreshButton'=>false)); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'verifyCode', array('class'=>'resume-form-input')); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Done', array('class'=>'button-style')); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Without knowing how you want this to be displayed, it's hard to say, but it sounds like you would want to apply `float: left` to both inner `<div/>`s or at least the `div.captcha`:

```
.captcha {
    float: left;
}
```

[Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/N32tC/) (I assume the rendered code looks something like that)

If you also want to get rid of the space between the text field and the button, give them a `float: left` too like in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N32tC/1/).

Comment: yes, "captcha" is displayed like "inline-block" element. I want to have row with 1 image, input text and button. And it works, but I've got problem with this space.

Comment: Well, remove `display: inline-block` from `.captcha`, add `float: left` like in my answer and wrap your input fields inside another div.